# Having Problems Clean Installing Osx El Capitan On Macbook Air 2010

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I have a bootable dmg file that I created using transmac on my pc. Everytime I load it up on my Macbook air it shows the prohibitory symbol after a few minutes.
I check on Disk utilitily first drive shows 60.67gb and the one under it shows 59.90gb. Every time I try to erase the top one it will say failed disk error cannot unmount but I'm able to erase the bottom one but yet it won't clean install the el capitan dmg bootable file from the usb. What am I doing wrong?
I already tried forcing the unmount through terminal and still won't work.

I tried reinstalling the previous Yosemite OSX through recovery but whenever i log it will say temporarily unavailable please try again later. So I'm stuck with a paperweight macbook air atm. Please help

Comment: WELCOME TO ASK DIFFERENT :) PLEASE DON'T PUT ALL CAPS IN THE TITLE IT IS INTERPRETED AS YELLING AND MAKES PEOPLE NOT WANT TO HELP YOU.

Comment: Sorry new to this place

Comment: Internet Recovery should install the original OS the machine was supplied with, from which you can update to the latest supported. Maybe see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos otherwise